# Is there a way to sign OS X packages on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, installation, signing

I'm trying to create packages for different OSs in a single Bamboo/Maven build, on Linux build agents.

Everything is working fine, including creating the OS X .pkg file.

The only problem is signing - there's a proprietary bit of software on OS X called 'productsign'. Is there any way to do this on a Linux box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way. Please see
http://users.wfu.edu/cottrell/productsign/productsign_linux.html .
You need openssl and recent xar; details at the link.

Comment: Please, make full reply, don't post links, as they will be changed through the time. You need to provide the code snippet, explicitly.

Comment: The linked resource has excellent instructions. Available on archive.org if ever needed: https://web.archive.org/web/20161203055739/http://users.wfu.edu/cottrell/productsign/productsign_linux.html

Comment: That uses bomutils which is now deprecated: https://github.com/hogliux/bomutils

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution like Wine for run MacOS applications on linux, is named Darling (https://www.darlinghq.org), but its not wall applications will be run, but your application is a specific component probably reduced dependencies, then, maybe run.